# Rabbit AMQPTemplate message send managed by EJB transaction manager

Tags: ejb, spring-amqp

I'm using spring amqp to place a message on a Rabbit queue within an EJB (stateless session bean).

When an exception is thrown out of the EJB container data updates are rolled back, is there anyway of getting the EJB container to manage the sending of the message in a similar way so that it is only committed to the queue when the EJB completes without an exception being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is:

1. Get rid of EJB at all
2. Use Spring TX Manager
3. And `RabbitTemplate` will do the stuff with TX sync for you automatically.

The issue with EJB TX sync (commit or rollback) that `RabbitTemplate` doesn't see the current TX, because it isn't managed by Spring.

If can make that EJB as Spring bean you will be able to provide `JtaTransactionManager` for EJB container transactions and mark EJB methods with `@Transactional`. But in this case the EJB doesn't make sence, because we do eveything with Spring here.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately there is currently plan to remove EJBs from the tech stack so this way is not for me. Might be for others though that are less reluctant to refactor out EJBs.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ doesn't have an XA-capable driver so no, it can't be managed by the container, the best you can do is set `channelTransacted` on the template and scope your EJB code with the `doInRabbit()` method...

```
template.execute(new ChannelCallback<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object doInRabbit(Channel channel) throws Exception {
         /// MDB logic + channel.basicPublish()
    }
});
```

Then, if an exception is thrown, both transactions will be rolled back.

However, if the EJB commit fails, the rabbit publish will have already been committed and won't roll back, so you should plan to handle (rare) duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, I can't find much in the way of documentation of ChannelCallback I see that I would have to use RabbitTemplate rather than AmqpTemplate is that correct?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/ChannelCallback.html It runs on the calling thread.

Comment: Unfortunately the reason for the queue is so the calling thread can be returned without having to wait for the message to be processed. I'm perhaps going to have a fiddle with Interceptors and ThreadLocal to send any pending messages after the EJB completes. Thanks again